# Runtime generated repositories and entities

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa, javapoet

In my SpringBoot application i'm generating hibernate entity classes and repositories using [javapoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet) and than compiling these generated source files respectively using [OpenHFT](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler) library **at runtime.** My purpose is being able to persist these runtime generated entities.

I could successfully use this generated entity inside my rest controller and map @RequestBody json String to this entity. **But my problem is i couldn't inject my runtime generated repository to the controller..**

Here is an example runtime generated entity;

```
@Entity
public class Author extends BaseEntity{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Author(){
        super();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
```

Here is the runtime generated repository for above entity

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.lang.Long;
import com.mrg.domain.Author;

@Repository("authorRepository")
public interface AuthorRepository extends GenericRepository<Author, Long> {

}
```

Here is the generic repository i'm using so that i can inject my repos at runtime

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericRepository<T, ID extends Serializable  > extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>{

}
```

And below is my rest controller. Here im autowiring generic repository as a Map so that Spring is injecting correct repository implementation dynamically when i use it with repository name as a key;

> genericRepo.get(repoName).save(model);

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/{entity}")
public class GenericRestController {


    @Autowired
    private Map<String, GenericRepository> genericRepo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{entity}/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Object createEntity(@PathVariable String entity, @RequestBody String requestBody) {

        Object model = null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String repoName = "";

        try {

            // ex : if {entitiy} param is equal "author" modelName will be "Post"
            String modelName = Character.toUpperCase(entity.charAt(0)) + entity.substring(1);

            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.mrg.domain." + modelName);
            model = clazz.newInstance();

            // Converting @RequestBody json String to domain object..
            model = mapper.readValue(requestBody, clazz);

            // Repository name is {entity} + "Repository" ex : authorRepository
            repoName = entity.concat("Repository");

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            // handling exceptions..
        }
        // Saving with right repository 
        return genericRepo.get(repoName).save(model);
    }
}
```

This is working for repositories that i wrote manually and i can persisting objects with this approach dynamically. But i couldnt access my runtime generated repositories.**(genericRepo.get("authorRepository") is returning null reference)**

Could you suggest a solution for this problem. What am i missing here? Any other idea for persisting runtime generated objects would be helpfull.

Thanks..

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem meanwhile? I would like to achieve the same...

Comment: Any progress? I faced a same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I faced with similar scenario, having to generate Repository at runtime to reduce boilerplate code. Through some research, it turns out that when scanning for interfaces annotated with @Repository, it's using ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider, which scans for classes in classpath, ignoring runtime-generated classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your repositories live in a package, for example com.mypackage.repository. In your config you should scan this package (and the package with controllers as well) so that Spring becomes aware of these beans:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = {"com.mypackage.controller"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.mypackage.repository"})
public class MyConfig {
    // creation and configuration of other beans
}
```

Config class may have more annotations for you own purposes (say, @EnableTransactionManagement, @PropertySource for props in text files). I just post the obligatory set of annotations.

Comment: Thanks but..I'm only using SpringBoot annotation here. Spring Boot automatically registers any repository that is found in any (sub)package relative to the SpringBootApplication annotation and annotated with Repository. So i dont need to use EnableJpaRepositories indeed. My problem is however if i generate my repositories at runtime in same package with existing repositories(that i wrote before compile time) Spring can not scan and recognize it as a repository.